# Should I be able use a metal wok spatula on a seasoned wok?

Tags: chinese-cuisine, seasoning-pans, thai-cuisine, wok

After a couple months of cooking with a wok my uncle gave me because he didn't use it, I was very pleased to see it seemed to be developing a nice patina.

[image: somewhat seasoned wok]

I cook with it, soak for a few minutes if necessary after eating, then wash with my normal sponge after I rinse the soap out of the sponge. Then I rub a tsp or two of peanut oil into it and heat until smoking before putting it away.

My understanding is that most traditional Chinese cooking uses metal wok spatulas. But when I bought one and used it this happened.

[image]

Am I doing something wrong with my seasoning? Or should I be using a wooden wok spatula?

Comment: I wonder if your cooking is a little western, e.g. you brown meat with little oil and often deglaze with acidic liquid (e.g. apple cinder and wine). Wok is more suitable for Chinese cooking where large amount of oil is used and meat never stick to the pan and form a fond, and deglazing is rarely used. If your cooking is low on oil, non-stick is much better, while if you brown and deglaze often, stainless is better.

Comment: Are you sure that's pressed steel? It looks a bit too shiny & 'white' where your seasoning has scraped off. It also looks very thick metal. I had a steel wok I used a chan [metal spatula] in for 20 years without taking the surface off like that.

Comment: I probably should use more oil, but I don't deglaze with acidic things. Maybe a little shaoxing wine mixed in the sauce.  I do not know what material it is since I didn't buy it myself unfortunately.